# AWS URL or URI?

Tags: python, xml, amazon-web-services

Hello I am interested in one thing.I know it can be silly question but I can not understand one thing here:

```
<CreateBucketConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <LocationConstraint>eu-central-1</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

is "http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/" URL or URI?

cause when I type it in browser it shows me this:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lzpnz.jpg)

Comment: It's both. A URL is a specific kind of URI. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's both. A uniform resource identifier (URI) provides a name for a resource. A URL (uniform resource locator) is a kind of URI that describes *where* (and how) the resource can be accessed.

The URL you provide, http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/, doesn't tell you anything about what is there. It simply says that if you use the HTTP protocol to connect to `s3.amazonaws.com` and request `/doc/2006-03-01/`, you'll get *something* back. What that something *is* is only implied by the name of the XML attribute that has the URL as its value.

(In practice, the server may not actually provide a resource at that location, but it *could*. The error message you see indicates there *might* be something there, but you don't have permission to access it.)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CreateBucket.html here is said to use this XML when requesting to create bucket but I can not understand very well one moment,when I send request why do I need to send this XML as well and what role is playing " http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/". I know that XML is used to send data,I read also about namespace in XML(xmlns),I read also about URI and URL. Separately I understand idea of these things,but when I wrote code to create request I am losing the idea,I can not understand what is happening actually(behind the scene).

Comment: That's an entirely different question than "Is this a URL or URI?"

Comment: yeah but I thought that my problem was in understanding  of URL and URI but you clarified this with your answer.So should I open new question and ask what I commented?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be better. (FYI, I don't know the answer to that question.)

Comment: Thank you for your attention.I appreciate this